# Filtering a foreign key in Django

Tags: python, django, filtering, querying

I'm trying to filter a foreign key, but it's not rendering any data, no matter the approach I use from examples.Here is the code

class Customer(models.Model):

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='customer',primary_key=True)
first_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)
last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

'

class Order(models.Model):

```
Distributor = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,)
Customer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                             null=True, related_name='customer_client')
```

The Views

```
def dashboard(request):
    orders = Order.objects.filter(Distributor=request.user)
    customers = orders.filter(Customer_id=1)
```

The template(snippet)

```
{% for customer in customers %}
                    <tr>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'distributor:customer' customer.user_id %}">View</a></td>
                        <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{customer.email}}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

i'm trying to filter the customers who have made the orders from a particular Distributor, kindly assist

Comment: Is there an order with `Customer_id=1` and with `request.user` as `Distributor`? It looks like there is simply no such `Order`.

Answer (score 0):

RUN THE ABOVE CODE AND LET ME KNOW THE RESULT ON THE TERMINAL, THEN I CAN HELP YOU FURTHER

```
def dashboard(request):
    orders = Order.objects.filter(Distributor=request.user)
    print(orders)
    customers = orders.filter(Customer_id=1)
    print(customers)
```

Comment: Its not formatted well, please format it in a way that is more readable

Comment: i have changed `customers = orders.filter(Customer_id=1)` to `customers = orders.objects.get(Customer_id=pk_test)` and it has brought this error _dashboard() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk_test'_ the terminal showed <QuerySet [<Order: KLKUS>, <Order: 7JORM>]>
<QuerySet []>
with the `customers = orders.filter(Customer_id=1)`

Comment: Change the "def dashboard(request):" to "def dashboard(request, pk_test):".

And then add the pk_test in the url

Comment: let me see the way you have configured your urls.py

Comment: `urlpatterns = [
    path('Dashboard', views.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
    path('customer/',views.customer, name='customer-only'),
    path('customer/<str:pk_test>/', views.customer, name="customer"),
    path('create_product/', views.createProduct, name="create_product"),
    path('create_order/', views.createOrder, name="create_order"),
    path('update_order/<str:pk>/', views.updateOrder, name="update_order"),
    path('delete_order/<str:pk>/', views.deleteOrder, name="delete_order"),
]` @coderboy

Comment: path('Dashboard/<int:pk_test>/', views.dashboard, name="dashboard"), try this i hope it works,

Comment: okay, whenever you get a solution, please kindly comment it here, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def dashboard(request):
customers = Order.objects.filter(Distributor=request.user, Customer_id=1)
```